# Jasmine -> Cannot read property subscribe of undefined when setting component up

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, ngrx-store

I have simple pipe in ngOnInit. On component creation error is thrown as in the title. 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at ShoppingCartListComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/customer-dashboard/user/shopping-cart-list/shopping-cart-list.component.ts:34:6)**

Where line 34 is .subscribe() on pipe.

Code looks like this:

component:

```
export class ShoppingCartListComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource;
  columnsToDisplay = ['title', 'location', 'date'];
  expandedElement: Event | null;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(selectEventsFromShoppingList),
      tap(events => this.dataSource = events),
    ).subscribe();
  }

}
```

tests:

```
fdescribe('ShoppingCartListComponent', () => {
  let component: ShoppingCartListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShoppingCartListComponent>;
  let storeSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    storeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Store', ["select","pipe"]);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ShoppingCartListComponent ],
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ], 
      providers: [
        { provide: Store, useValue: storeSpy }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShoppingCartListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

What am I missing here? Should I provide some default state? Or maybe try with spOn().and.returnValue ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that `storeSpy` is an object that contains a bunch of uninitialized spies. You need to add a return value to `pipe` as well. You could do something like this:

```
subscribe.pipe.and.returnValue(jasmine.createSpy())
```

There are other options, but this is the simplest.